# Applying array formula which is already once applied in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This formula i have applied in a sheet

```js
={"Stukprijs"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C; SORT(FILTER({Inkoop!D2:D&Inkoop!E2:E&Inkoop!F2:F \Inkoop!G2:G\ ROW(Inkoop!G2:G)}; Inkoop!B2:B="Heinsberg"); 3; 0); 2; 0)))}
```

i want to apply this same formula in another sheet but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setFormula` in a cell.

#### Example:

- Copying formula to Sheet2!A1

#### Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2") ;

var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
cell.setFormula("={\"Stukprijs\"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C; SORT(FILTER({Inkoop!D2:D&Inkoop!E2:E&Inkoop!F2:F \Inkoop!G2:G\ ROW(Inkoop!G2:G)}; Inkoop!B2:B=\"Heinsberg\"); 3; 0); 2; 0)))}");
```

#### Note:

- Don't forget to escape some characters, like `"`. Simply add `\` before every `"` when inside another `"`. See above.
- The formula you pasted above is having a parser error. Please fix the formula above so it will not cause an error when copied into another cell.